# Access denied on edit in excel

Tags: excel, infrastructure

Has anyone seen an error occur when a user performs the edit in excel action and the user gets an authentication prompt which they can't get past with their correct credentials and then a similar error occurs as if the server had gone offline (Office 2003 on Win XP against WSS 3.0 SP2)

The users can get to the document fine via other methods i.e. if the download a copy from SharePoint instead of edit.
It looks like the error is down in the RPC layer as the call is to author.dll and the following is logged.

`10/12/2009 09:26:28.62 w3wp.exe (0x0D90)                       0x02D8 Windows SharePoint Services   General                                       72ng      Medium               RPC method = checkout document

10/12/2009 09:26:28.87 w3wp.exe (0x0D90)                       0x1274                                  1463                                       8l41        High                    assertPermissionMask was called, but permissions haven't been computed yet.`

Any suggestions on fixes or ways to debug would be great !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have now confirmed it was not an office client thing or anything to do with SharePoint settings. There was one sever in the farm that was set to use the /3GB OS switch which is not compatible with SharePoint and was causing this strange behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this behaviour before and it was caused by having an office 07 app installed with an office 03 app on the same client. running the office repair wizard fixed the issue on that occasssion.

Answer (score 0):

which version of Office 2003 are you using.

only the professional version has sharepoint support.

Answer (score 0):

HI,

Did you try dis abling Checkout/Check in on the document Library?